# Changing ID values in MySQL database with SQL command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in my MySQL database where the `id`'s of the entries starts from `3000` because the previous rows were deleted. What I would like achieve is to change the value of the `id` columns. I would need the rows to start from `1`. If I have `1900` entries, I would need the `id`'s from `1` to `1900`. The id column in my database is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and the `id` is primary key.

My question is that is it possible to achieve this with an SQL command? Or I should rather create a new database and transfer the objects with new `id`'s?

Comment: My question is "why?"

Comment: The first question is: Why do you care? It's a really bad idea to change primary keys. If the table is referenced by any other table, then you will have referential integrity issues.

Comment: In a nutshell, the id's are used in url's and must start from 1. @CaiusJard Jard

Comment: Why must they start from 1?

Comment: But what if another few records are deleted later? You should not be relying on contiguous values for the keys. However, if you must, and if the table is referenced by other tables, then your best bet is to `SELECT` the records into a new table, temporarily drop your foreign key constraints, then replace the references to the `ID` from the old table with the new `ID` (you will need to match up your records), then create the new foreign key relationship and finally drop the old table. _Is it worth all that?_

Comment: Not wishing to sound harsh but "Because they go in a url" might be among the weakest of reasons I've heard for having contiguous IDs that start from 1 - sounds like security breach waiting to happen.,

Comment: If you need explicit numbering, I would suggest adding a new column just for that.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43137256/5031885

```
UPDATE table_name SET id  = 0 - id;
set @counter = 0;
UPDATE table_name SET id  = (@counter := @counter + 1);
```

This will first set all id values to negative equivalents and then will loop each row, update and increment the counter.

This solution will not work if id column is unsigned.
Also, keep in mind that this will not change the current AUTO_INCREMENT pointer.

To help with auto-increment you can use:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Even if we assign 1 to AUTO_INCREMENT, it will continue with the next key as it should.

Comment: What do you recommend to do about foreign keys?

Comment: If you declared foreign keys with `ON UPDATE CASCADE` then they will also get the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You should better drop the column and again add it as it will surely lead to inconsistancy of data as its a primary key plus if it becomes a foreign key as a reference in other table then it would create more problems even after dropping the column

You need to drop the column and then add it again with autoincrement and if it is also a foreign key then you have to drop the constraints from both the tables using CASCADE.

Comment: Only after _all_ records have been deleted. If you do this when there are still records with id 3000+, then the next id will be 1 greater than the last record in the table. It will not renumber the records.

Comment: Did you mean 301 would be the value starting with. Yeah i guess i did it wrong umm.. will update i guess better option is to drop this column and again recreate it

Comment: No — the better option is to forget about renumbering primary key values.